# Any references for parsing incomplete or incorrect code?

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, heuristics

Can anybody point me at references on techniques for parsing code that contains syntax errors, or is missing necessary punctuation, for example?

The application that I'm working on is an IDE, where we'd like to provide features like "jump to definition", auto-complete, and refactoring features, without requiring the source to be syntactically correct at the moment the functions are invoked.

Most parser code I've seen appears to work on the principle of "fail early", rather than focusing on error recovery or parsing partially-complete code.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)?

In "[The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference)", section 10.7 Automatic Error Recovery Strategy for 5 pages Terrence talks about this. He references [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs](http://www.worldcat.org/title/algorithms-data-structuresprograms/oclc/1324351&referer=brief_results), [A Note on Error Recovery in Recursive Descent Parsers](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=947905), [Efficient and Comfortable Error Recovery in Recursive Descent Parsers](ftp://www.cocolab.com/products/cocktail/doc.pdf/ell.pdf).

Also see the pages from the web site:

- [Error reporting and recovery](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery)
- [ANTLR 3.0 Error Reporting and Recovery](http://www.antlr.org/blog/antlr3/error.handling.tml)
- [Custom Syntax Error Recovery](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery)

Also check the [ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/antlr/info) tag for accessing the ANTLR forum where Terrence Parr answers questions. He does answer some questions here as [The ANTLR Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275496/the-antlr-guy).

Also the new version of [ANTLR 4](http://www.antlr4.org) is due out as well as the [book](http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=antlr%204%20book#query:antlr%204%20book%20page:1%20mid:i3lb7an3mkupvn4z%20state:results).

Sorry to sound like a sales pitch, but I have been using ANTLR for years because it used by lots of people, is used in production systems, has a few solid versions: Java, C, C#, has a very active community, has a web site, has books, is evolving, maintained, open source, BSD license, easy to use and has some GUI tools.

One of the people working on a [GUI](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/2.+Grammar+Editing+Features) for ANTLR 4 that has syntax highlight and auto-completion among other useful IDE editing is Sam Harwell. If you can reach him through the ANTLR forum, he might be able to help you out.

Comment: Interesting - ANTLR apparently now has a Javascript source generator. That might make it a more reasonable candidate for a clean-sheet redesign of the existing parser. Thanks for the error recovery links - they give me an idea of what's supported for recovery options other than single-symbol insert & delete.

Comment: @MarkBessey I am not sure if the JavaScript target is maintained. I posted a status question to the ANTLR forum for you. You can check it at http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=#query:+page:1+mid:dsv33hegehdr7wh3+state:results without sigining up. :)

Comment: @MarkBessey The last post from the author of the JavaScript target is here http://antlr.markmail.org/search/?q=Joey+Hurst#query:Joey%20Hurst+page:1+mid:cdn4hfexethqo67s+state:results. Note that it was only alpha then and the author has not been on the forum since.

Comment: Well, worst case, it's still a potential source of ideas.

Comment: @MarkBessey While you are making the right decision to avoid the current JavaScript version for ANTLR consider this: the code is open source and BSD license. You are more than welcome to pick up the existing JavaScript target, which is alpha, and make it work. I can not help do the conversion, but the ANTLR forum will give you what help they can. Someone is right now looking into doing a Ruby version of ANTLR from scratch. You can follow it on the ANTLR forum.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know of any papers or tutorials, but [uu-parsinglib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib-2.7.3.4) is a Haskell parsing library that can recover from syntax errors in a general fashion. If, for example, `;` was expected but `int` was received, the parser can continue as though `;` were inserted at that source position.

It’s up to you where the parser will fail and where it will proceed with corrections, and the results will be delivered alongside a set of the errors corrected during parsing. Even if you don’t intend to implement your parsing code in Haskell, an examination of the library may offer you some insight. Or you can write a parser in Haskell and [call it from C](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C).

Comment: Will check it out for ideas, at least. I'm going to be implementing this in Javascript, so the Haskell library itself isn't likely to be useful for me as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Research on "Island grammars" may interest you. It's been a while since I looked at them, but I believe that they are supposed to reasonably handle cases where there are many chunks of nonsense in the file. I didn't have much luck with CiteSeer (oddly; usually it's pretty good), but [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=island%20parsing&btnG=&as_sdt=1,22&as_sdtp=) found a number of relevant papers. [Generating robust parsers using island grammars](http://vefur.simula.no/~leonm/papers/wcre2001/wcre2001.pdf) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: Oh, excellent. This addresses the issue of how to extract *some* information from code that can't be parsed, as opposed to single-symbol insertion and deletion, which is a more typical error-recovery mode in traditional compilers.